# Pandas groupby merge_asof

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes `left` and `right` that I want to merge based on a grouping in `df1`.

```
df1:

ID              cumul_growth_perc
Nioz-TC-09-A1R  0
Nioz-TC-09-A1R  2.99881756777804
Nioz-TC-09-A1R  90.1974001442841
Nioz-TC-09-A1R  92.7010664317585
Nioz-TC-09-A1R  95.4937993952028
Nioz-TC-09-A1R  97.7300790074048
Nioz-TC-09-A1R  100
Nioz-TC-09-A2R  0
Nioz-TC-09-A2R  2.1989297984251
Nioz-TC-09-A2R  4.25561486642024
Nioz-TC-09-A2R  82.2910739802899
Nioz-TC-09-A2R  93.276493352502
Nioz-TC-09-A2R  95.5072381936874
Nioz-TC-09-A2R  97.5983443147713
Nioz-TC-09-A2R  100
```

```
df2:

day cumul_growth_perc
32  0.233297611918821
33  0.466595223837642
34  0.699892835756464
35  0.933190447675285
36  1.16648805959411
37  1.39978567151293
46  3.54027808151455
47  3.78173847397982
48  4.02319886644508
335 92.4313101347799
336 92.6888317371006
337 92.9463533394213
338 93.203874941742
339 93.4613965440627
340 93.7189181463834
361 99.0468989121531
362 99.2851741841149
363 99.5234494560766
364 99.7617247280384
365 100
```

`cumul_growth_perc` is ranging from 0-100, but was shortened here for demonstration. I want to merge both dataframes on this column and the values don't match exactly in `df1` and `df2`.
Additionally, `df1` should be grouped by the `ID` column before performing the matching. As I understand it, pandas `merge_asof` specifically has the `by=` keyword to do this. But as I don't have the `ID` column in `df2`, the operation fails. `df2` is the same for all groups of `df1`.

Here is what I used:
`pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='cumul_growth_perc', left_by='ID', direction='nearest')`

As expected, it tells me `right_by is missing`. How can I still perform the "grouped merge"? I could just extend `df2` by appending the same values for each unique value in `df1.ID`, but that feels hacky.

**EDIT:**

Expected output:

```
                ID  cumul_growth_perc  day
0   Nioz-TC-09-A1R           0.000000   32
1   Nioz-TC-09-A1R           2.998818   46
2   Nioz-TC-09-A1R          90.197400  335
3   Nioz-TC-09-A1R          92.701066  336
4   Nioz-TC-09-A1R          95.493799  340
5   Nioz-TC-09-A1R          97.730079  361
6   Nioz-TC-09-A1R         100.000000  365
7   Nioz-TC-09-A2R           0.000000   32
8   Nioz-TC-09-A2R           2.198930   37
9   Nioz-TC-09-A2R           4.255615   48
10  Nioz-TC-09-A2R          82.291074  335
11  Nioz-TC-09-A2R          93.276493  338
12  Nioz-TC-09-A2R          95.507238  340
13  Nioz-TC-09-A2R          97.598344  361
14  Nioz-TC-09-A2R         100.000000  365
```

Meaning i want to group by `df1.ID` before performing the merge. I made it work by "repeating" `df2` with an additional `ID` column for each ID of `df1`:

```
for i, name in enumerate(df1.Shell_ID.unique()):
    if i==0:
        df2_long = df2.copy()
        df2_long['ID'] = name
    else:
        temp = df2.copy()
        temp['ID'] = name
        df2_long = df2_long.append(temp)
```

Then both dataframes were sorted by `cumul_growth_perc` and I merged them with `pd.merge_asof(df1, df2_long, on='cumul_growth_perc', by='ID', direction='nearest')`

But it feels like there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: What do you do with the group in df1? Can you please post an expected output?

Comment: Edited the question accordingly

Comment: @cripcate I think the value at row with `index=3` should be `336`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma sorry I did it per eye, I will edit in a minute.

Comment: @anky So I found out that this grouping is not really needed, as `merge_asof` does the same thing when I omit the `by` argument. The only thing differing to my own solution are the first three rows.

Comment: @cripcate So you don't need groupby?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma yes, turns out I don’t!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) sort the dataframes `df1` and `df2` on `cumul_growth_perc` then perform [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) on the sorted dataframes:

```
d1 = df1.sort_values('cumul_growth_perc')
d2 = df2.sort_values('cumul_growth_perc')

df = pd.merge_asof(d1, d2, on='cumul_growth_perc', direction='nearest').sort_values('ID')
```

Result:

```
                ID  cumul_growth_perc  day
0   Nioz-TC-09-A1R           0.000000   32
1   Nioz-TC-09-A1R           2.998818   46
2   Nioz-TC-09-A1R          90.197400  335
3   Nioz-TC-09-A1R          92.701066  336
4   Nioz-TC-09-A1R          95.493799  340
5   Nioz-TC-09-A1R          97.730079  361
6   Nioz-TC-09-A1R         100.000000  365
7   Nioz-TC-09-A2R           0.000000   32
8   Nioz-TC-09-A2R           2.198930   37
9   Nioz-TC-09-A2R           4.255615   48
10  Nioz-TC-09-A2R          82.291074  335
11  Nioz-TC-09-A2R          93.276493  338
12  Nioz-TC-09-A2R          95.507238  340
13  Nioz-TC-09-A2R          97.598344  361
14  Nioz-TC-09-A2R         100.000000  365
```

Answer (score 1):

use`tolerance` and `direction` parameter   , you can define how close values should be between themselves . as you see `value  2.998818`  have `ID` `NAN` because there wan no close value from second df in 3.0 interval for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "cumul_growth_perc": [2.99881756777804,90.1974001442841,92.7010664317585],
    'day':['one','two','three']
})
print(df)
   cumul_growth_perc    day
0           2.998818    one
1          90.197400    two
2          92.701066  three


df2= pd.DataFrame({
    "cumul_growth_perc": [92.9463533394213, 93.203874941742, 84.00],
    'ID':['first','second','3rd']
}).sort_values(by='cumul_growth_perc')

print(df2)
   cumul_growth_perc      ID
2          84.000000     3rd
0          92.946353   first
1          93.203875  second

res = pd.merge_asof(df,df2,on='cumul_growth_perc',tolerance=3.0,direction='nearest')

print(res)
   cumul_growth_perc    day     ID
0           2.998818    one    NaN
1          90.197400    two  first
2          92.701066  three  first
```