# Find closest values in dataframe column based on values in column in another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, match, closest

I have two dataframes, one with a "full" time series and another with far fewer elements representing special points in time for an experiment with many trials. The time variable runs from 0 to x for a given trial then resets to 0 for the next trial. The data looks like this (images) where the full time series has labels for each trial and t_coords (time) that will increase until trial changes to 2. At that point t_coords resets for a new trial and increases again until trial 3 and so on:

coords_df: full time series per trial

```
   subject  trial  t_coords x_coords y_coords
0     1010      1      1239     6.50     0.50
1     1010      1      1351     6.50     0.50
2     1010      1      1918     6.38     0.52
3     1010      1      2031     6.28     0.53
4     1010      1      2143     6.16     0.55
5     1010      1      2256     6.06     0.57
6     1010      1      2370     5.95     0.58
7     1010      1      2486     5.83     0.59
8     1010      1      2600     5.73     0.57
9     1010      1      2709     5.61     0.54
```

full_navs1_df: special time points; need to use object_appear_time and trial_num

```
   subject x_coords y_coords  t_coords  trial  object_num  
0     1010    10.50     3.50      8023      1           1   
1     1010     3.50     9.50     68156      1           2   
2     1010     8.50    11.50     82894      1           3   
3     1010     4.50     2.50    116226      1           4   
4     1010    10.50     6.50    131060      1           5   
5     1010     5.50     5.50    161710      1           6   
6     1010     3.50    10.50      8018      2           1   
7     1010     9.50    10.50     51981      2           2   
8     1010     2.50     6.50    106287      2           3   
9     1010     7.50     6.50    123758      2           4
```

I need to find the index of the closest value to each of the special time points for each trial, so the answer has to also take into account trial. The values in the special time points df won't have exact matches in the full time series df, hence desire to get the closest value. I have been unsuccessful trying to figure out how to perform a nearest value function while also looping through each trial. By way of example the first value of the full_navs_df['object_appear_time'] is 8023. The closest value in the coords_df['t_coords'] column appears at index 62 (not shown, but the output for the 8023 value for trial would be 62). That process would repeat for each object_appear_time AND trial.

I've seen solutions and variants such as:
`df.iloc[(df['num']-input).abs().argsort()[:2]]`

but this doesn't require iterating over multiple rows in multiple columns from different dataframes. Other solutions that use merge wouldn't work due to the fact that there are multiple time series in the same column (resets every trial).

---

Edit with solution attempts:

Reproducible Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'subject': subject_ex,
                'trial': trial_ex,
                't_coords': t_coords_ex})

    subject  trial  t_coords
0         1      1      1304
1         1      1      1603
2         1      1      3000
3         1      1      3658
4         1      1      4763
5         1      1      5364
6         1      1      6129
7         1      2      1298
8         1      2      1874
9         1      2      3328
10        1      2      4192
11        1      2      4783
12        1      2      5439
13        1      2      6193
14        2      1      1307
15        2      1      1787
16        2      1      2599
17        2      1      3675
18        2      1      4783
19        2      1      5362
20        2      1      6126


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'subject': subject2_ex,
                'trial': trial2_ex,
                't_coords': t_coords2_ex})

   subject  trial  t_coords
0        1      1      3230
1        1      1      6090
2        1      2      1909
3        1      2      4801
4        2      1      2499
5        2      1      5400
```

Expected Output:
Some way to get the indices that correspond to the t_coords in df2 in df1:

```
   index
0      2
1      6
2      8
3     11
4     16
5     19
```

Attempted the following:

```
df1_sorted = df1.sort_values(['subject', 'trial'])
df2_sorted = df2.sort_values(['subject', 'trial'])

time_indxs = pd.merge_asof(df2_sorted, df1_sorted, on='t_coords', direction = 'nearest').sort_values(['subject','trial'])
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: left keys must be sorted
```

Comment: PLEASE do not include pictures of data or code. Use three tildas to wrap your code block

Comment: How should your desired output look like? IIUC you want to have a new column in the df `full_navs1_df` where each row has the index of the closest match in `coords_df`. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct output. So for example the first output corresponding to the value of 8023 for trial 1 would be index 62 (not shown... but 62 corresponds to 8077 in the coords_df['t_coords'] column.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630670/pandas-groupby-merge-asof). It looks very similar to me.

Comment: It seems like it might work but I realized I really need to sort twice... one for subject and one for trial (i.e. subject 1 trial 1.... subject 30 trial 1.... etc.). I've tried this: `time_indxs = pd.merge_asof(coords_df, full_navs1_df, on='t_coords', direction = 'nearest').sort_values(['subject','trial'])` and get error: `ValueError: left keys must be sorted`

Comment: like in the accepted answer of the link. first sort both seperate df's, then use the `pd.merge_asof` and sort the merged df again.

Comment: I did try doing that, but I'm not sure how to handle the two other critical variables of subject and trial. In the link, there's just one ID and that variable only appears in one of the DFs. I have all 3 variables appear in both dfs. Thanks for your patience, I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get exactly where you are stuck. Just to double check. your code looks something like this: `coord_df = coord_df.sort_values(['subject','trial'])`, same thing for the other one, and then the code you posted in the comments? If you still can't figure it out, you need to create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Just two little example df's with few groups to represent your task, and a desired output to that specific little example. That would be the best to get concrete help.

Comment: Thank you please see edited post above with reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into your example, I also couldn't figure it out with `merge_asof`.
Here is what I would do.
You basically go through each row of your second df, filter the first df by the current group (subject and trial) and then build the difference between the current t_coords with all times of the first (filtered) df. The smallest result of that difference will be the row you are searching for (which is achieved with `idxmin`).

```
find_index = (
    df2
    .apply(lambda x: 
           (
               df.loc[(df['subject']==x['subject']) & (df['trial']==x['trial']), 't_coords'] - x['t_coords']
           )
           .abs()
           .idxmin()
           , axis=1)
)
print(find_index)
```

Output:

```
0     2
1     6
2     8
3    11
4    16
5    19
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, many thanks. Glad I wasn't missing anything obvious with merge_asof.